# Filter specific elements of ordered array of objects, based on values of previous objects (aggregation framework)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have these documents:

```
[
    {
        '_id': 1,
        'role': [
            {  // keep this document
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-01')
            },
            {  
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-02')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-03')
            },
            {  // keep this document
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-04')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-05')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-06')
            },
            {  // keep this document
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-08')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-01-09')
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        '_id': 2,
        'role': [
            {  // keep this document
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-05')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-06')
            },
            {  // keep this document
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-07')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-08')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'free',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-09')
            },
            {  // keep this document
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-10')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-11')
            },
            {
                'plan': 'pro',
                'date': ISODate('2020-02-12')
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So I have to filter documents, based on the change of the value of `plan` field.
I always want to keep the first occurence, but the next document will only be kept if the value of `plan` field has changed (e.g. `free` changed to `pro`, or `pro` changed to `free`).

**Obs.**: I have more distinct values for the `plan` field (e.g. `premium`, `admin` etc), but I only got two documents for the example.

Comment: You can use the aggregation array operator [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to get the desired result.

Comment: I'm seeing the `$reduce` documentation and seems this could really solves the problem. I tried this but doesn't solved the problem: `{ '$addFields': {
  t: {
    $reduce: {
      'input': '$roles',
      'initialValue': {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$roles', 0]
      },
      'in': {
        $cond: {
          'if': {$eq: ['$$value.plan', '$$this.plan']},
          'then': '$$value',
          'else': '$$this'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}`

Comment: @igorkf : Try this query : https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qx4OEt0SvT1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this operation might be an overkill if done on huge dataset & dataset having `role` array with lots of objects in it. You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** As `role` field already exists `$addFields` will overwrite with new value */
    {
      $addFields: {
        role: {
          $let: {
            vars: {
              data: {
                  $reduce: {
                  input: { $slice: [ "$role", 1, { $size: "$role" } ] }, /** array input without first object */
                  initialValue: { roleObjs: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$role", 0 ] } ], plan: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$role.plan", 0 ] } }, /** Pick first object & first object's plan as initial values */
                  in: {
                    roleObjs: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.plan", "$$value.plan" ] }, "$$value.roleObjs", { $concatArrays: [ "$$value.roleObjs", [ "$$this" ] ] } ] }, /** Conditional check & merge new object to array or return holding array as is  */
                    plan: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.plan", "$$value.plan" ] }, "$$value.plan", "$$this.plan" ] }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            in: "$$data.roleObjs" /** Return newly formed `roleObjs` array in local variable */
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VGJhWjJk3GD)

Comment: Yeah, it worked just like I need. Why you think this could be an overkill?

Comment: @igorkf : As usual problem iteration on list/array will always be an issue in development, no matter which language/where it is :-) If dataset or array size is more then I thought it might perform slow or may exceed aggregation's individual stage's limit of 100MB of RAM(though it might be rare for this kind of ops). If it works great for your dataset then you're good to go :-)

Comment: I got it. Maybe this problem is due to the how the data was constructed. I think this could be avoided planning a better way to construct this type of data. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @igorkf : Yes data design prior to storing is very crucial & always neglected or overseen, as usual - common issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an aggregation with the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ 
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          plans: { 
              $reduce: { 
                  input: "$role", 
                  initialValue: [], 
                  in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$this.plan" ] ] } 
              } 
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: {
          role: { 
              $reduce: {
                  input: { $range: [ 0, { $subtract: [ { $size: "$role" }, 1 ] } ] },
                  initialValue: { prevPlan: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$plans", 0 ] }, roles: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$role", 0 ] } ] },
                  in: {
                      $cond: [ { $eq: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$plans", "$$this"] }, "$$value.prevPlan" ] },
                               { prevPlan: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$plans", "$$this"] },
                                 roles: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value.roles", [ ] ] } 
                               },
                               { prevPlan: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$plans", "$$this" ] },
                                 roles: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value.roles", [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$role", "$$this" ] } ] ] } 
                               }
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $project: { role: "$role.roles" }
  }
] )
```